# Node.js Error invalid left hand assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js

what is wrong with this code

```
aboutRoute.get("/", (req, res)=&gt;{
    const aboutInfo ={
        name: properties.name,
        description: properties.description,
        author: properties.author
    }
    res.json(aboutInfo)
})
```

I get the following error

```
C:\Users\choup\Desktop\weathermicroservice\routes\about.js:6
aboutRoute.get("/", (req, res)=&gt;{
                    ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    a
```

how to come over this issue, please

Answer (score 1):

Imm... you asking `what's wrong in code?`, Im saying that the function you assign is wrong. You should not use html-encoded codes IG.

```
aboutRoute.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    const aboutInfo ={
        name: properties.name,
        description: properties.description,
        author: properties.author
    }
    res.json(aboutInfo)
})
```